# Why is the error count divided by 2 in the nn.test function in deepnet R package?

Tags: r

I do not understand why there is '/2'(divided by 2) in the calculation of error_count in the nn.test function in the deepnet R package, as shown below.

```
function (nn, x, y, t = 0.5) 
{
    y_p <- nn.predict(nn, x)
    m <- nrow(x)
    y_p[y_p >= t] <- 1
    y_p[y_p < t] <- 0
    error_count <- sum(abs(y_p - y))/2
    error_count/m
}
```

To me, "error_count <- sum(abs(y_p - y))" is correct. Can anybody explain why they put the '/2' there?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Questions about specific design decisions in R packages might be better addressed to the author of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at it, my best guess would be that `error_count <- sum(abs(y_p - y))` would not only count to the left of the prediction, but also the offset to the right of the prediction.  Since you are calculating error twice, you divide by two.

Comment: Thank you. But only once that I calculated the error.

I used the small dat below to test the function
trainX:
1    0
0    1
1    1
trainY:
1
1
0

testX:
1    0
0    1

testY:
0
0

nn <- nn.train(trainX, trainY)
nn.predict(nn, testX)
0.7167006
0.7166937
nn.test(nn, testX, testY)
0.5

I think the error rate should be 1. Since both predicated values are greater than 0.5 then the predicated classes should be both 1, but the actual classes are both 0, so the error rate should be 1.

Can you explain what do you mean by “left” and “right”?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you ever get to the bottom of this one? As I see this you are right, it should not be divided by 2 unless there is some error rate definition here that I am not aware of and does not correspond to the actual error count. If I run test on X, Y (0/1 classification) I get an "error rate" of 20% but if I simply use predict on X with the same network to get the predictions and then compare them to Y, the "error count" is actually 40%.